# Java Servlet leading to HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting a strange error with one of my many servlets when I try to click on a button from my jsp file. None of the other post regarding HTTP Status 404 and Java Servlets seem to having any relevance with what I am encountering.

**HTTP Status 404** - Not Found 
**Type** Status Report 
**Message** /ProjectName/pages/LogoutServlet 
**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

**Note**: No warnings or exceptions are appearing in the console when I click on the  button.

This is a Dynamic Web Project being run on Apache Tomcat v9.0.

**JSP File (Name: loginSuccess.jsp)**

```
<body>
    <%
        String user = null;
        if(session.getAttribute("user") == null){
            response.sendRedirect("pages/index.jsp");
        } else {
            user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
        }
        String userName = null;
        String sessionID = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if(cookies !=null) {
            for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
                if(cookie.getName().equals("user")) {
                    userName = cookie.getValue();
                }
                if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")) {
                    sessionID = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        } else {
            sessionID = session.getId();
        }
    %>

    <h3>Hi <%=userName %>, Login successful. Your Session ID=<%=sessionID %></h3>

    <br>

    <form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
    </form>
</body>
```

The form at the bottom of the JSP above is the giving me the error.

**Java Servlet (Name: LogoutServlet.java)**

```
package com.main;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/LogoutServlet")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if(cookies != null){
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
            if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
                System.out.println("JSESSIONID="+cookie.getValue());
            }
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
        }
        //invalidate the session if exists
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        System.out.println("User="+session.getAttribute("user"));
        if(session != null){
            session.invalidate();
        }
        response.sendRedirect("pages/index.jsp");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }

}
```

Please note that i am declaring the servlet with the **@WebServlet** annotation instead of adding the servlet and the servlet mapping in the web.xml file.  I have around 20 other servlets in this application with a similar setup.  This servlet is the only one that I am having this issue with.

The application never reaches the LogoutServlet when I run in Debug mode.

**Java Servlet (Name: LoginServlet.java)** *This is my servlet that leads the user to the loginSuccess.jsp

```
package com.main;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Connection con = null;
        boolean validated = false;

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=root";
            Properties dbInfo = new Properties();
            dbInfo.put("user", "root");
            dbInfo.put("password", "root");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbInfo);

            String sql = "SELECT uname, pword FROM bankofme.accounts";

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()) {
                if(user.equals(rs.getString("uname")) && pwd.equals(rs.getString("pword"))) {
                    validated = true;
                }

            }
            rs.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        if(validated) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1800);
            Cookie userName = new Cookie("user", user);
            userName.setMaxAge(1800);
            response.addCookie(userName);

            String encodedURL = response.encodeRedirectUrl("pages/loginSuccess.jsp");
            response.sendRedirect(encodedURL);
        }else{
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("pages/index.jsp");
            PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
            rd.include(request, response);
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**JSP File (Name: index.jsp)**

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
    </div><!-- end of header -->
</body>
```

Comment: *404 Not Found* for `/ProjectName/pages/LogoutServlet`, but you Servlet is just `/LogoutServlet`, so unless your webapp context path is `/ProjectName/pages`, it's no wonder you get "Not Found". Perhaps `/ProjectName/LogoutServlet` would be the right URL?

Comment: Well the message isnt the url necessarily.  the url should lead me back to /ProjectName/pages/index.jsp. The logoutservlet path is src/main/java/com.main.logoutservlet.java

Comment: The `LogoutServlet ` **path** is the webapp context path (i.e. `/ProjectName`) plus the path given on the `@WebServlet` (i.e. `/LogoutServlet`), so the `LogoutServlet ` path is **`/ProjectName/LogoutServlet`**. I don't know why you think *that* path has `pages` in it.

Comment: I can try to change it around, but this is the same logic that I implemented with my LoginServlet that is also posted above

Comment: I see what you are getting at, but I am not sure how to tell java to point to ProjectName/LogoutServlet instead of ProjectName/pages/LogoutServlet

Comment: `../LogoutServlet` perhaps?

Comment: trying to change it to ../LogoutServlet threw org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start

Comment: What is the path folder of login.jsp and index.jsp pages. Your servlet url in a jsp html code is relative to the current page url path. Most likely this is a difference between working and failing servlets.